# how to count filtered columns in a table

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I'm trying to make this code works

```
For Each dest In destSS

    Hoja8.ListObjects("BD").range.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:= _
        Array(dest), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        Hoja8.ListObjects("BD").range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
    "<=.8", Operator:=xlFilterValues
With Hoja8.ListObjects("BD").Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=range("BD[Load Status]"), Order:=xlDescending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=range("BD[Destination]"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=range("BD[Current Location]"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=range("BD[Event]"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=range("BD[Dwell]"), Order:=xlDescending
    .Apply
End With
    
    On Error Resume Next
Set myRange = Hoja8.ListObjects("BD").DataBodyRange.CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If myRange Is Nothing Then

'Do nothing

Else
    'do stuff
    Sheets("BD").Activate
        range("A1").Select
        With Hoja8.ListObjects("BD")
          Union(.ListColumns(9).range, _
            .ListColumns(1).range, _
            .ListColumns(3).range, _
            .ListColumns(5).range, _
            .ListColumns(8).range, _
            .ListColumns(10).range, _
            .ListColumns(15).range, _
            .ListColumns(17).range, _
            .ListColumns(19).range).Select
    
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Recently Placed").Select
 'check ifs there any data in the sheet and if there are, find the last row to paste the data--------------
       
      If WorksheetFunction.CountA(range("C1").CurrentRegion) = 0 Then
        range("C1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Else
        
        lscol = range("C" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
        
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
        
    
End With
        Set myRange = Nothing
     End If
Next

        columns("G").Cut
        columns("C").Insert
 
Call SortDB



 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It runs fine but when the filtered data shows nothing it's still copying the header and when I put a -1 it doesn't copy any data at all, can you help me out here?

I tried this code and runs but when the filter shows nothing on the rows still copies the header

Comment: `Hoja8` or `sheet8`  ?  You use both in your code to refer to the (same?) sheet

Comment: ...also you only need to sort the table once: you can do that before the loop over `destSS`

Comment: thank you Tim im going to edit the question with all the code on it

Answer (score 2):

### 'Reset' Object Variable When In a Loop

- Since this code is in a loop, you want to reset `myRange` i.e. right before the `End If` that belongs to `If myRange Is Nothing`, use the line `Set myRange = Nothing`.

```vb
For Each dest In destSS

    ' Whatever

    On Error Resume Next
        Set myRange = sheet8.ListObjects("BD").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If myRange Is Nothing Then

        ' do nothing

    Else

        ' do stuff 

        Set myRange = Nothing ' right here!!!
    End If

Next dest
```

Comment: thank you! for your replies guys, i added the Set MyRange = Nothing but still the code copies the header when theres nothing in the filtered table

Comment: You have to remove `.CurrentRegion`, otherwise it will do just that!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code...

```
On Error Resume Next
With sheet8.ListObjects("BD").Range
    Set myRange = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End With
On Error GoTo 0

If Not myRange Is Nothing Then

    'example to copy filtered data, including headers
    sheet8.ListObjects("BD").Range.Copy Sheet2.Range("a1")
    
    'example to copy filtered data, excluding headers
    myRange.Copy Sheet3.Range("a1")
    
End If
```